# Generating random logo colors on each hover event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am doing a website for a friend and I am currently working on the social network elements.

I came up with an idea in my head, that whenever the user hovers over on of the social network images, it will randomly change the background color (on each hover) to one of his company logo colors.

This is my first project and I am trying to show future employers that I can use functions, arrays, conditions, objects within my coding.

Here is my code

HTML:

```
<section id="social">
<ul>
<li><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x"></i></li>
<li><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-instagram fa-3x"></i></li>
<li><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-3x"></i></li>
<li><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-youtube-square fa-3x"></i></li>
</ul>
</section>
```

JQUERY / JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    logoColors = [
    rgb(182,131,0),
    rgb((118,0,96),
    rgb(0,85,88),
    ];

    randomCol = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);

    $("#social li").hover(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", logoColors[randomCol]);

    })



});
```

Comment: And the issue is..?

Comment: You need to set `randomCol` *inside* the `hover` handler. You'll also need to set the colour back to normal on `mouseout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try this :

1. I have defined both `mouseover` and `mouseout` events
2. `mouseover` sets a random background , `mouseout` reverts back to
   original
3. Original/initial color is retained in a variable
4. done randomization of color inside functions

Other than this there are some errors like stray parenthesis in `logoColor` array, in order to avoid such issues validate your JavaScript code in [JsLint](http://www.jslint.com/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    //logoColors = [rgb(182,131,0),rgb((118,0,96),rgb(0,85,88)];
    var initialCol = $("#social li").css('background-color');
    var colors = ["#CCCCCC","#333333","#990099", "#1295A6", "#FFFF99"]; 

    

   // $("#social li").hover(function(){
       // randomCol = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
       // $(this).css("background-color", logoColors[randomCol]);

    //});
    
    $("#social li").hover(function() { //mouseover
    var col = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);
    $(this).css('background-color',colors[col]);

}, function() { //mouseout
    $(this).css('background-color',initialCol);

});



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="social">
<ul>
<li><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x"></i></li>
<li><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-instagram fa-3x"></i></li>
<li><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-3x"></i></li>
<li><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-youtube-square fa-3x"></i></li>
</ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var defaultColor = "white";
        var logoColors = [
          'rgb(182,131,0)',
          'rgb(118,0,96)',
          'rgb(0,85,88)',
          'rgb(155,0,44)',
          'rgb(80,85,88)',
          'rgb(118,50,96)',
          'rgb(40,85,88)',
        ];

       $("#social li").hover(function(){
           randomCol = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
           $(this).css("background-color", logoColors[randomCol]);

       }, function() {
           $(this).css("background-color", defaultColor);
       });

});
```

working JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/79fhdtu2/

Answer (score 0):

Fixes:

1. One parentheses is extra in your rgb color declaration.
2. Take colors in double quotes.
3. Math.Random should go upto 3 because Math.floor() returns the largest integer ***less than or equal to*** a given number.

For extra effect, changing color on each link hover, you can declare randomCol variable inside hover function.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

         logoColors = [
        "rgb(182,131,0)",
        "rgb(118,0,96)",
        "rgb(0,85,88)",
        ];

        var randomCol = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

        $("#social li").hover(function(){
            $(this).css("background-color", logoColors[randomCol]);

        })
    });
```